# Swift 3 - Delete row with userdefaults

Tags: swift3

Hopefully someone can help, I have a recording app, the recordings save to userdefaults then shows on a table view. I cant delete the row and the data from userdefaults. I am wondering if anyone knows how I can delete the selected rows. If you need any more information please let me know.

```
var numberOfRecords:Int = 0

guard let data = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myNumber") as? [String] else {
        return
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let path = MainVC().getDiretory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: getDiretory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row - 1).m4a"))
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "myNumber")
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is not working? Deleting the row from the TableView? Deleting the data from userdefauls?

Comment: @Marcelo at the moment both

Answer (score 0):

You check the data source you are using, for example; you set you recording information on an array, which in it you return the count of table's rows. Then when you delete the item, you remove it from the array so that when you reload the table, it will be removed.

As for the file itself; it seems you are saving it in another directory or deleting another file with different key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will give this a go then I will get back to you.

Comment: Is it possible if you can show me on how I can do this?

Comment: If you can, show me your code and I will check it for you

Comment: Okay will do. Do you think it will be easier to use core data?

Comment: From what you wrote, you have simple data, as recording and its attributes, so I don't think you need core data or database, but you know your app better.

Comment: Your comment is not clear, using int where? And you mean put into array or into a string?

Comment: Sorry I got confused with something else. I have edited the code.